# Как сделать 2 домена сайту на wordpress? Чтобы в рф был домен ru, а за границей домен com?

Tags: wordpress, хостинг, домен

Мне надо, чтобы в России сайт могли найти по домену ru, а за границей могли найти только по домену com.

Comment: Что значит "могли найти"? Ничто не мешает ввести в России домен.com, а за границей домен.ru.

Comment: Речь идёт про один и тот же сайт? Или хотя бы про разные локализации?

Comment: Про один сайт..